# there is already an open DataReader associate with this Command which must be closed first

Tags: c#

> "there is already an open DataReader associate with this Command
>   which must be closed first."

when I 'search' "name" the data from a search button. I am getting this error.

This is the code:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * from New_table where Name = @name", conn);
                selectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("name", textname.Text.ToString()));
                SqlDataReader reader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();
                bool rowFound = reader.HasRows;
                if (rowFound)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        textname.Text = reader.GetString(0).ToString();
                        txtaddress.Text = reader.GetString(1).ToString();
                        txtcontact_no.Text = reader.GetString(2).ToString();

                        SqlDataAdapter data = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from New_table", conn);
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        data.Fill(dt);
                        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                        MessageBox.Show("Search Found", "Form", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("User Not Found", "Form", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is why you should always use [using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) statement.

Comment: The logic of this code doesn't make sense to me.  Why are you trying to query the same table twice?  Why are you re-binding to the entire table over and over in a loop?  Why are you overwriting the values of form controls in a loop?  What *should* this method be doing?

Comment: Proper opening and closing of connection will be helpful for you. Its a bad practice of letting your connection open.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to execute two queries or batches in a single connection and hence the problem.There are two ways to resolve.

1.Store the read data from sql reader somewhere globally and again call sql adapter with new connection and input this data.

2.Or Use Multiple Active Result Sets property in your conection string so that you  multiple batches can be execute on a single connection

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=MSSQL1;" +   
    "Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=SSPI;" +  
    "MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
```

**Note**:By the way you should avoid such scenario.